# How to handle a private key SSL certificate with Ansible

Tags: ssl-certificate, encryption, ansible, configuration-management

I'd like to deploy my webserver config with [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html).

Is there any way to keep the SSL cert private key encrypted, and to decrypt it when the playbook is started?

The reason is that I want to to use Github's private repositories. But the file will still be in the cloud and one click away from exposure.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773294/how-to-upload-encrypted-file-using-ansible-vault

Comment: I somehow have to get something like that for files, when the certs are not inline in the playbook.

Comment: I don't think it possible with vault for now, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7298, https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/13849 and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/14079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html).

Is short, it's a way to store encrypted YAML files, which can be decrypted directly by Ansible.

You then would run ansible with `--ask-vault-pass`:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: Yes, that works if I have the cert in the playbook. But I want to copy a file.

Comment: You could get the same result by using the `lineinfile` module and writing the line from an ansible var which is stored in the encrypted file.

Comment: hmh I am new to Ansible. The file have to be used because there is a checker which makes sure they are valid etc. I guess I will use the command module and pipe the file through a decrypter

Comment: @udondanyou can also use "copy" to write a string, or a single var in a template.